# Could we have a link to the SO sites (StackOverflow, ServerFault, SuperUser) in the links part of the page for Area51 sites?

Tags: feature-request

The links at the bottom of each page for Area51 sites contain just about every other Area51 site as well as the Apps/Api site.  There are no links to the original SO sites.  Could this be added?

[image]

Comment: Isn't that by design though?  All the sites listed there are xxx.stackexchange.com

Comment: Aren't SO, SF & SU also really just the first stackexchange sites?